# How to get rid of backslash added before user name when switching users in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, login-screen, username

On a computer running Windows 7 with a custom local GPO (Group Policy Object), when switching from the user to Administrator, the username has a backslash prepended to its name. Hence forth it is impossible to logon; the password does not work. When logging off the user (instead of switching)  the problem does not occur. Here's a screenshot of the prepended `\`:

[image]

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you see, your question text is quite vague... thank you :) Additionally, are you sure you mean user `root`... Windows/*nix??

Comment: Which GPO? Who is root? Where do you see a slash? The post as it is now is impossible to understand.

Comment: Here is a reproduction of the screen (The computer is not connected to the internet) - https://goo.gl/zrHKIF
The meaning of root is adiminstrator - fixed the question.
GPO cannot be uploaded here, slash comes before the user's username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: Switch User and force logon to local computer:

1. Click Switch User > Other User (if applicable)
2. When prompted for the username, enter `.\<username>` (e.g. `.\johndoe`). Don't neglect to leave of the preceeding `.\` which specifies that you want to logon the local computer.
3. Enter the account password and logon as normal

### Solution 2: Prevent Windows from remembering the last username used to logon:

1. Open the Registry Editor by running `regedit.exe`
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
3. If it doesn't exist, create the value `dontdisplaylastusername` and specify the data type of DWORD.
4. Set the value `dontdisplaylastusername` to **1**

Alternately, you can accomplish the above through Local Group Policy ([Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a7c061c2-7a62-4a97-b16c-7edfa754fbe6/clear-last-logon-user-name)):

1. Run `gpedit.msc`
2. Navigate to Computer\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
3. Set the setting **Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name** to `Enabled`

### Solution 3: Clear the last username used to logon Windows ([Source](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/90-clear-the-last-logged-in-username-at-windows-login)):

1. Open the Registry Editor by running `regedit.exe`
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
3. Delete the data from the values `DefaultUserName`, `AltDefaultUserName` and `DefaultDomainName` (don't delete the values themselves)

Comment: The 3rd solution was the closest one. After deleting the value (.\) from DefaultDomainName, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to such a user, return to screen where you can enter user name and password and use fully qualified user name:

```
PC-NAME\Username
```

e.g.

```
HOMEPC2\Paul
```

I suppose your computer name is not blank. Blank name shouldn't be normally possible, but it came upon my mind seeing `\Paul`. Normally that screen would show `HOMEPC2\Paul`.